# How to show a popup window after a pin is clicked with Xamarin.Forms.GoogleMaps

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, xamarin.android, maps

Right now, my code looks like this:

```
       private void AddIvy()
        {
            Pin one = new Pin()
            {
                Label = "Ivy",
                Position = new Position(38.021436330, -78.653405170),
                Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("Recycle")
            };

            MyMap.Pins.Add(one);
            one.Clicked += onIvyClicked;
            MyMap.MoveToRegion(MapSpan.FromCenterAndRadius(new Position(38.021436330, -78.653405170), Distance.FromKilometers(10)));
        }

        async private void onIvyClicked(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Ivy());
        }
```

When the pin `one` is clicked, the pop up page `Ivy` should appear. It says that `one.Clicked` is obsolete and to change it to `MyMap.PinClicked`. However, changing the code to `MyMap.PinClicked` makes `Ivy` pop up for every pin on my map. How can I change the code so that `Ivy` only pops up when `one` is clicked?

Comment: it's bad UX to have a Pin on the map that the user **can't** click on.  If I had an app that behaved that way I would think it was broken

Comment: Could it work ?

Answer (score 0):

The **Pin** class defines a `MarkerClicked` event, which is fired when a Pin is tapped.

you could  try to use like:

```
Pin one = new Pin()
{
    Label = "Ivy",
    Position = new Position(38.021436330, -78.653405170),
    Icon = BitmapDescriptorFactory.FromBundle("Recycle")
};

one.MarkerClicked += async (s, args) =>
{
    await PopupNavigation.Instance.PushAsync(new Ivy());
};
```

the more you could refer to [Interact with a pin](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/xamarin/xamarin-forms/user-interface/map/pins#interact-with-a-pin).